# After I use malloc, program suddenly asks for input

Tags: c, malloc

I'm a newbie programmer

```
//allocating space for final output
//text_count is given by another function, let's just say i have a value for it
//out is my typedef struct

out *fin[text_count];

for(i=0; i<text_count; i++){
  fin[i] = malloc(sizeof(out));
}

//this is a test
fin[1]->appearances = 1;

printf("%d",fin[1]->appearances);

// ..other code
```

I noticed that after this allocation, program suddenly outputs this:

```
1_
```

The underscore is blinking, indicating it needs an input.

What can be my problem here? Is it the allocation? Or the codes down below?

okay sorry, let me clarify this, im using codeblocks . so when i get a blinking cursor it means it needs an input. and after i got this output, an infinite loop of inputs seems to be happening.

Comment: `the underscore is blinking, indicating it needs an input` No, it doesn't... I think you are young, and rarely (if ever) saw an ASCII text screen or much less used one actively...

Comment: Is it seriously "sudden", considering you actual call `printf()` short after your stated `malloc()` loop? I could surmise your problem could be an infinite loop in `// ..other code`, maybe check there. (this, assuming you expected your code to finish and the program to *end* a some point).

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code given. Problem is somewhere else

Answer (score 3):

You're simply seeing the text terminal's cursor. It may be blinking or it may not, that doesn't mean anything in itself.

You might want to add a linefeed:

```
printf("%d\n", fi[1]->appearances);
```

to get the output on a line of its own.

Answer (score 0):

A cursor after your printf does not mean, that it is waiting for input.

You can confirm this, by using `strace`, if it is waiting at `read` syscall.

Usage:
`strace ./myApplication arg1 arg2...`